# SpringSecurity and HTTP Based Authentication

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm new in Spring Security...

I have a web application, with HTTP Based Authentication, on Bea Weblogic. I want to set-up the SpringSecurity also, and I want logout with this.

My web.xml is:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>AlkalmazasNev</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>jog</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

Is it possible? Which filters must I set-up for SS?

Thank you for your help.

Sorry, my English isn't very well...

Gabi

Comment: In my project which uses spring security I only have the filter and filter mapping setup.  They should be enough to get a basic version of Spring Security up and running.

Comment: Ohh, thanks... then it may be something else wrong :(

Comment: Well, it works on Tomcat really, but doesn't work on Weblogic yet...

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing Spring Security's configuration with the standard servlet-specification offered by the web container. The `security-constraint` and `login-config` elements in your `web.xml` are handled by the web container (Weblogic in this case).

It's not really a good idea to mix these with a Spring Security configuration. I'd suggest you look at some of the [sample applications](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/samples) that come with Spring Security, or follow [one of the spring.io guides](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/).

Adding Basic authentication to replace the container support is quite straightforward. An example using Java configuration is shown [in the manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-httpsecurity). With the XML namespace you would add `<http-basic>`.

If you have specific questions or errors you need help with after that, then you can post them here.